# Passing a multiline string in Vimscript to an external script

Tags: vim

I am passing visually selected vim text to a Ruby script using:

```
system("echo -n " . shellescape(var_holding_selected_text) . " | my/ruby/script")
```

The script isa able to read the text from STDIN, but I find that all the newlines are preceded by a backslash. I gather that this is because the `shellescape` function escapes newlines. I have two questions:

- why does `shellescape` escape the newlines and/or null bytes if it also quotes the string? Apparently the quoting of the string is enough, because I am receiving literal backslashes as a result of the escaping in my script.
- is there a better way to pass the text to my ruby script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative that circumvents all the escaping problems (and potential size limitations of the shell command-line) would be to write the text to a temporary file (using `tempname()` and `writefile()`), and just passing or `:cat`ing that filename to the Ruby script. Then, clean up with `delete()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a way with [Claytron's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34530/claytron) help:

```
silent execute '!printf "\%s" '. shellescape(a:text, 1) .' | nc localhost 2224'
```

printf should pass through the entire contents of shellescape without interpretation.